# Software for Circuit Design and Simulation for Ubuntu 18

Tags: linux, ubuntu, simulation, electronics

I'm looking for a software for designing and simulating electrical circuits on Ubuntu 18. I'm familiar with Eagle and quite like it but can't get it to run on my Ubuntu machine. Best to have both design and simulation in 1 software but having 2 separate programs is also OK.

Edit:

I'd like to be able to design and simulate medium-complexity circuits. I'd like to make some boards that run with micro-controllers but just simulating simple ones is fine. I'd like one I can install on my machine and work with in real-time rather than web-based. I don't really have a budget to spare so I'd like something free. (Eagle trial version worked fine fore me on Windows)

Answer (score 1):

What about software-as-a-service offers? With https://www.circuitlab.com/ you can run simulations in your Browser. It is commercial software, subscription-based.

I don't know how well this can scale up. Maybe the web can handle only simple circuits.